# How do you replace the "smiley" button with a return key in an EditText?

Tags: android

How do you replace the "smiley" button with a return key in an EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.  Stop using the imeOption `textShortMessage`.

Comment: thanks man, this drove me crazy for a while, all the time the softkeypad was mocking me with its smiley wee face!

Comment: not in the the imeOptions. in inputType. android:inputType="textShortMessage"